# Invalid APK when running project

Tags: apk, android-install-apk

I have a problem with the APK when I'm trying to run my project. I've tried to clean/rebuild my project and it worked. But finally, my project doesn't show the map I've inserted...

Comment: You should add some more context to your question. F.e. what kind of map did you add, and how? Can you show some code or is there an error message you see?

Comment: SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cafe);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

Comment: @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String textposition= String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

                if (textposition=="ΚΑΠΗΛΕΙΟ ΤΟΥ ΜΑΡΚΟΥ"){
                    mMap.clear();
                    LatLng καπηλειό= new LatLng(37.444530, 24.943903);
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(καπηλειό).title("Marker in Το Καπηλειό του Μάρκου"));

Comment: mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(καπηλειό));
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17.0f));   }

Comment: I don't think I can help you with this. But you should at your code snipped directly to the question. You can click the `edit` button on the bottom of your question. If you add your code to the question instead of writing it in comments its easier for people to read and its more likely that you will get some help. Good luck!